# How do "area downvote" posts emerge and is there a way to avoid it becoming political?

Tags: discussion, voting-fraud

I have encountered this situation a few times, and it's slowly been starting to worry me. I can't fully analyze the backstory of these events, since I can't fully look behind the voting scenes.

I'm referring to posts like https://stackoverflow.com/q/34525814/2003898, where I posted an answer that kinda' "trolls" the OP, where my answer provides the advice to use `printf()` statically containing the sequence the OP wants (with a note that this solves his problem with respect to the named restrictions).

My post almost instantly got 2 downvotes. A short time after that it even got 1 vote for deletion. Whilst I would agree that upvoting my post is questionable, it is not worth downvoting and especially not deletion. It is a valid answer (albeit probably not what OP is looking for, but that is the fault of the OP's imprecise requirements).

What so ever.
A short time after that, 2 other answers appeared, and both got a downvote at the same time. After a third answer came in, all 3 prior answers (mine and the first two) got downvoted once again, and the new answer got 2 downvotes as well.

So being the only one with 3 downvotes, which almost obviously came from the contenders, I downvoted them as well just to even the scores.

Now, on that post, almost everyone is downvoting everything even if its content doesn't justify it. So there are even quality answers with negative score now.

**Is there a political way to avoid these situation?** Are there any automated ways planed to detect and prevent this, akin to the script that detects serial voting? And is there anything else known about causes of this behaving (i.e. significant styles of OPs causing discussion like voting behaviour by being too opinion based)?

Comment: So, you admit to posting "troll answers" and are surprised at downvotes? Bad answers get downvotes.

Comment: Also - not liking your revenge downvoting - without even knowing _who_ downvoted your answer.

Comment: well I'm able to count views, answers and votes. Same way as I can be sure that you downvoted this post by seeing it has 4 views and 3 downvotes ;) Downvoting this post and saying my behaving is not ok contradicts... I know that this behaving isn't ok, thats why I psoted this, where I'm stating I noticed this happening a few times allready and asking for any counter meassures. So justify your voting on this post please.

Comment: _"which came almost obvious from the contenders"_ Please do provide your fact based research to back this up, otherwise don't throw around accusations and just shrug the loss of a few rep points off. Further more, votes on meta is different from on SO (if you didn't know), a down vote might simply mean that they disagree with your opinion. - Don't ask people to change their votes just because you don't like it.

Comment: @Epodax: I asked no one to change anything. I just asked for justifications. Thats an big difference. And well the voting on this post clearly shows that my worrys .... aren't supported(?) and there is no such thing like counter downvoting?! well I HAVE such meassures from previous cases but I don't see any reason for making the effort to provide them if, if anyway no one takes me serious. Personally I really don't care about it. But his meta post I stated from an community point of view just out of my perspective to the linked case.

Comment: Voting is anonymous. No one is forced to give a reason (and that is by design and will not change).

Comment: _" I HAVE such meassures from previous cases but I don't see any reason for making the effort to provide them if, if anyway no one takes me serious."_ Why should people take you serious if you don't make a proper case? Show your research / back up your statement with proper data and people will most  likely take you more serious, but making claims without any proper data to support you is the same as finding a man guilty of a crime simply because you **believe** him to be so.  - And I'm not saying there isn't a issue with "counter down voting", I'm just saying that you shouldn't point fingers.

Comment: @Oded: I would say it is semi anonymous if there is not an hidden feature to prevent what happens here. Since this post had 4 views and 3 downvotes after you commented on it, your anonymity was obviously broken by system. But anyway I can feel to request what ever I want, can't I? I never said you are obligated to justify, so I don't see why your comment even mattered.

Comment: Again, you are making **an assumption**. In particular about my voting. You have circumstantial evidence (oh, and number of views - which you assume is real time, which it isn't) - which doesn't tell you anything actual.

Comment: @Epodax: The only person I'm actually pointing on is my self.... And I just did that to avoid anyone saying "Hey but you were trolling".... And to discuss it from a neutral point of view. But after no one so far even gave any statement except starting judging me, I'm reall not that much caring....

Comment: No. You are telling us there is a problem, without showing us the research to show it is indeed a problem. All you have is a gut feeling. Additionally, you have told us of your wrong-doing (and it ways that show you **know** it is wrong). Of course people respond to that as well - we are just human, you know?

Comment: @Oded and again MY question is: Why does this even matter? I just asked for justification based on an assumption. Am I forbidden to do so??? You aren't forced to even react on it.... to calrify it or to don't... But just to notify: Since reactions on this post aren't on topic by ANYONE, not even the comments of diamond user(s) so far, I won't take any reaction on it anymore if it isn't related to the OP problem itself....

Comment: You are making an assumption, which I believe is wrong. I can't justify a negative here.

Comment: _"which came almost obvious from the contenders"_ Seems like a finger pointed at the other people who answered, none the less. This is not about you, this is about the post you have made, if you want people to take it more seriously, then provide some research to back up your claims, otherwise this is just a rant.

Comment: @Oded: Thanks, tahts all I wanted to hear. I wasn't clear about that there are insufficient datas about this. I assumed there would be (What I introductional staated by not having tools to analyze it.) So now I realize even the critism about my post here. But how should I have known that?!

Comment: @Epodax: I could take out the example if it helps. Just thought providing an actuall case would help. I guess my whole situation is completly misstaken... What I wanted to show here is: MY behaving was wrong because I(!!!) >assumed< they were it. so I(!!!) decided to make something unethical just to even the scores. thats what my intention of the example was to show of. I wasn't judging the contenders for anything on an meta kind of view. And thats also why I did not understand why my behaving was made to an topic in this OP. Since I just wanted to project my own bad behaving into an metaview.

Comment: Or should I in future cases better ask someone else to write this kind of meta post ABOUT me, so it sounds less like an rant BY me?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**You're really overcomplicating the story.**

People came, saw the question, saw that it was bad and downvoted it. Some looked at the answers, saw that they were bad and downvoted them.

No serial or competitive voting is needed. No questionable or shady voting practices are needed. You can blame the OP for not being clear enough (and, indeed, should feel free to do so with an accompanying downvote), but that is no excuse for writing a poor answer. A comment in the same vein (to demonstrate that the OP should be more clear in the question) would be more appropriate.

---

With regards to detecting serial downvotes from other answerers: that is exactly what the reputation cost of downvotes is for. But you can't just automatically reverse them; it could just be that the other answers *are bad*.

Unlike the user-voting case, where it's not deemed acceptable to trawl through and vote on many of a user's answers at once, reading and discussing alternate answers to the one you're about to answer is good form. Not doing so, after all, risks duplication.

Answer (score 22):

> Is there a political way to avoid this situations?

Sure. Don't troll.

> is there anything else known about causes of this behaving?

Yep. Bad answers get downvoted.

---

Now, the main thrust of your question is the assumption that there is a lot of "strategic downvoting" of competing answers.

Though this *does* happen occasionally, the -1 rep penalty associated with downvoting an answer tends to curb such voting. It isn't something that is common or happens often.

It is also not something one can **know** is happening, as voting is anonymous - the fact is, a bad/trolling/joke answer will attract downvotes. This *may* be by others who answers (who are naturally more invested in having *good* answers, given they have put an effort into answering the question in the first place), but is just as likely as to have been by others who happened upon it.

Comment: You know that all your content on this OP is jsut trolling in it self?! I seriously try to treat this serious and provide content to something that is at least in my eyes an harmfull behaving. And all the response to it by an diamond user is trolling on an literarily meta level? This leaves a really sad picture of your name to me. but I guess you don't care...

Comment: @Zaibis - I am being very serious here. You tell us you give troll answers. These are badly accepted and you wonder why. I explained why. You don't like the explanation and you accuse *me* of trolling. This is certainly a case of the kettle calling the pot black.

Comment: I never said I wonder why. I even said I know why, just to prevent making it a topic here.... and actually its the only topic....

Comment: So, your issue is with "strategic voting", which you have failed to show as an actual thing. This is not something you have proven (or can prove).

Comment: What about Replacing your answer with your last comment? So your answer is at least related to my Question and not related to something I did earlyer today?